# Array of Arrays to Array of Objects and back

Tags: javascript, json

I need a generic method to take an (array of arrays)+(header array) and convert it to an JSON array of objects and then convert it back to an array of arrays. The 'unpack'/'pack' methods in the the SQLike library at http://www.thomasfrank.se/SQLike/ do this. For various reasons, I really don't like this library and would prefer to use something else. Can anyone recommend a solution?

to clarify, i want to go back and forth between these two data 'structures':

```
1) var headers = ['col_1', 'col_2'] 
   var data = [['x0', 0.34],['x1', 0.35]]

2) var objArr = [[{col_1: 'x0'},{col_2: 0.34}], [{col_1: 'x1', col_2: 0.35}]]
```

I can't create the object template every time, because I am reading all kinds of data from google sheets. I therefore need a generic method of some kind that do this.

Comment: I assume 2) should not have sub-arrays, so should look like `var objArr = [{col_1: 'x0', col_2: 0.34}, {col_1: 'x1', col_2: 0.35}]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the array of named to create properties in objects from the data in the arrays:

```
function toObjects(headers, data) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var o = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
      o[headers[j]] = data[i][j];
    }
    result.push(o);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Then use the headers to read properties from the objects and put in arrays:

```
function toArray(headers, data) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var a = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
      a.push(data[i][headers[j]]);
    }
    result.push(a);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: out of curiosity is this sort of thing built into any of the populal libraries?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/tp3nk4zf/2/

```
var headers = ['col_1', 'col_2'];
var data = [['x0', 0.34], ['x1', 0.35]];

function unpack(headers, data) {
    var unpacked = [], obj, i, il, n, nl;
    for (i = 0, il = data.length; i < il; i++) {
        obj = {};
        for (n = 0, nl = headers.length; n < nl; n++) {
            obj[headers[n]] = data[i][n];
        }

        unpacked.push([obj]);
    }

    return unpacked;
}

function pack(headers, data) {
    var packed = [], arr, i, il, n, nl;
    for (i = 0, il = data.length; i < il; i++) {
        arr = [];
        for (n = 0, nl = headers.length; n < nl; n++) {
            arr.push(data[i][0][ headers[n] ]);
        }
        packed.push(arr);
    }
    return packed;
}

var unpacked = unpack(headers, data);
var packed = pack(headers, unpacked);
console.log(unpacked, packed);
```

Comment: The `pack` function also needs the headers. Using `for (prop in data[i][0])` doesn't return the properties in a predictable order.

Comment: Thanks Guffa.  I upvoted yours, but also updated my answer.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Note that as Guffa mentioned in comments, the order of the values inside the arrays in pack, i.e. the order the header array is generated, is not guaranteed to be the same as when it was unpacked, but the headers and values do match up.

```js
function unpack(headers, values) {
    var result = [];
    for(var v = 0; v < values.length; v++) {
        var arr = values[v];
        var obj = {};
        for(var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            obj[headers[i]] = arr[i];
        }
        result.push(obj);
    }
    
    return result;
}

function pack(values) {
    var result = [];
    var headers = null;
    for(var v = 0; v < values.length; v++) {
        var obj = values[v];
        if(headers == null) {
            headers = [];
            for(var p in obj) {
                headers.push(p);
            }
        }

        var arr = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = obj[headers[i]];
        }

        result.push(arr);
    }
    
    return { headers: headers, data: result };
}


var headers = ['col_1', 'col_2'] ;
var data = [['x0', 0.34],['x1', 0.35]];

var unpacked = unpack(headers, data);
console.log(JSON.stringify(unpacked));

var objArr = [{col_1: 'x0', col_2: 0.34}, {col_1: 'x1', col_2: 0.35}];
var packed = pack(objArr);
console.log(JSON.stringify(packed));
```

Comment: The `pack` function also needs the headers. Using `for (var p in  obj)` doesn't return the properties in a predictable order.

Comment: @Guffa Yes good point I hadn't thought of, but depends if header order is important - the values will still line up with the headers correctly.

Comment: yes, unfortunately header order is important. I'm in the world of Spreadsheet macros over here.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job fine =)

```js
var pack = function(headers, data) {
  return data.map(function(row) {
    return row.map(function(column, i) {
      return Object.defineProperty({}, headers[i], {value: column});
    });
  });
};
var unpack = function (packed) {
  var headers = [];
  return {
    data: packed.map(function(row) {
      return row.map(function(column, i) {
        var key = Object.keys(column)[0];
        if (headers.length !== row.length) {
          headers.push(key);
        }
        return column[key];
      });
    }),
    headers: headers,
  };
};
console.log('pack', pack(['col_1', 'col_2'], [['x0', 0.34], ['x1', 0.35]]));
console.log('unpack', unpack([[{col_1: 'x0'}, {col_2: 0.34}], [{col_1: 'x1'}, {col_2: 0.35}]]));
```